# tshark.exe: capture traffic without content, only headers of packets

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, tshark, network-traffic

Please tell me which keys to use to run the tshark utility to record only the network packet headers

If using the command:

```
.\tshark.exe -i "Ethernet" -w d:\traffic.pcap
```

it writes all traffic, which eats up too much disk space

Answer (score 1):

From the [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) man page:

> **-s|--snapshot-length**
>
> Set the default snapshot length to use when capturing live data. No
> more than snaplen bytes of each network packet will be read into
> memory, or saved to disk. A value of 0 specifies a snapshot length of
> 262144, so that the full packet is captured; this is the default.

This won't give you the packet headers per se, but rather it will simply limit the maximum number of bytes captured per packet.  So, if you're mostly interested in TCP/IP traffic transmitted over Ethernet framing, and assuming standard IP and TCP header sizes, you can try a snaplen of 54 (14 bytes Ethernet, 20 bytes standard IP header and 20 bytes standard TCP header).

Comment: good!
Can you tell me what the maximum header size can be? (if you need not only TPC packages, but all packages in general)